# Docker build ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.5.1

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I have a Dockerfile that has the following format:

```
FROM python:latest
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "script.py"]
```

Where my requirements.txt looks like:

```
grpcio==1.31.0
grpcio-tools==1.31.0
torch==1.5.1
```

When I execute `docker image build .` I get the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  61.44kB
Step 1/7 : FROM python:latest
 ---> dfc47c6cee13
Step 2/7 : ADD requirements.txt .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3be914d5b849
Step 3/7 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 372c329c76fa
Collecting grpcio==1.31.0
  Downloading grpcio-1.31.0.tar.gz (20.0 MB)
Collecting grpcio-tools==1.31.0
  Downloading grpcio-tools-1.31.0.tar.gz (2.1 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This was a strange error to receive because if I recall correctly, torch was able to be installed fairly recently (as early as 2 weeks ago), so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the version in the Dockerfile by instead of doing

```
FROM python:latest
```

changing it to

```
FROM python:3.7.4
```

I suppose that torch has an issue with installing python3.9.0, which is what python:latest was updated to a couple days ago. Better to force the docker container to work with a specific known version :)